# Duplicated symbols under Xcode 8.2.1 because of CardIO's opencv static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv, paypal

I couldn't add the opencv.framework through CocoaPods nor manual manner because the CardIO dependency seems to have an opencv static library embedded which conflicts with another opencv pod that also seems to have a version of the opencv static library.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the CardIO SDK and instead of adding into pod, add the CardIO lib directly into your project and add the required frameworkrs.
2. Add "OpenCV" into your pod file.
3. Go to terminal, cd to your project's directory
4. run `pod install`

You can test your app now, I hope it will work. Thats how I resolved the same issue in my case.

Comment: how i rename class name in static library in cocapod?

Comment: "if you have opened sources" i said

Answer (score 0):

@farid You can use **opencv** in pod, Download **CardIO SDK** and add it into your project, It should work. Thats how i resolved for this issue